# Select typed word in input using mouse in Angular application

Tags: angular, input, kendo-ui, multi-select

I am creating a custom angular dropdown with a search bar(input). I am preventing autofocus of the dropdown option pallet and again focusing on input at the same time. After the above behavior, the typed word could not select using the mouse.

This is the component that I have developed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5j3gp-d6bust?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, Try out below code

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[selectableTextForMouse]'
})
export class SelectableTextForMouseDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('mousedown', [ '$event' ]) onMouseDown($event: Event): void {
        $event.stopPropagation();
    }

    @HostListener('touchstart', [ '$event' ]) onTouchStart($event: Event): void {
        $event.stopPropagation();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.style['user-select'] = 'text';
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.style['cursor'] = 'initial';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).